# Java Syntax error in regexp pattern during the removing trailing comma

Tags: java, android, regex, whitespace

i have the string like this:

```
{"ssid":"TEST", "key_mgmt":"NONE",  "priority":"102",}
```

And I'm trying to remove last comma after the last attribute.

```
,}
```

Using the:

```
.replaceAll("(,[[:space:]]*})", "}")
```

But it throwing following error:

```
Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 15:
(,[[:space:]]*})
```

How can i solve it please?

Note: is it Java used in Android SDK.

Comment: You should try `,\s*}`. The parentheses are optional in your case.

Comment: I just tested it in normal Java, and it runs fine. This might be related to Android SDK, but I am not familiar with it. It indicates the error comes near `}`. Maybe you need to escape it with a backslash?

Comment: Are you sure Java supports `[[:space:]]` type expressions?

Comment: Try `.replaceAll(",\\p{Space}*}", "}")`, or to match any Unicode whitespace, use `.replaceAll(",\\s*}", "}")`.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to use a look ahead `?=` to search to `}`, when it is found you can now match the comma `,` that is before it, and the replace the comma with an empty string `""`

*An example in java*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         String l="{\"ssid\":\"TEST\", \"key_mgmt\":\"NONE\",  \"priority\":\"102\",}";
         String m=",(?=})";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(m);
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(l);

        System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(""));

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"ssid":"TEST", "key_mgmt":"NONE",  "priority":"102"}
```

Comment: There's no need to call `find()` before you do a `replaceAll()`, and you especially don't need to put it in a loop.  `replaceAll()` does all the finding and looping itself.

Comment: Also, the OP's regex was fine aside from using the wrong character-class syntax.  Your lookahead proposal doesn't solve the problem, and there's no compelling reason to use it instead of what the OP is doing.

Comment: Your example throws Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 5: In Android "Java".

Comment: I doesn't throw any error. Make sure, you copy exactly what was posted

Answer (score 0):

What is space? Give this a try:

```
.replaceAll(", ?}", "}")
```

If you want to test, try this site: https://regex101.com/